# Find the basis of polynomial subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Question: show that $W$ which is set of all polynomials in $P_n$ such that $p(-x) = p(x)$ is subspace of $P_n$ and find the basis for it!

"I know, how to prove it subspace!" Further, clearly 
  $Dim\ W = Dim\ P_n - 1 = n+1 - 1 = n $

So there must be $n$ vectors in basis! But I unable to determine its basis! Please help me..

Comment: Your dimension computation is wrong. Start by finding simple examples of polynomials in $W$ and not in $W$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.If $p(x) = p(-x)$ for all  $x$, then it follows that $p$ contains only even powers of $x$.

To see this, note that if $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_ip^i$ , then $p(-x) = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^ia_ip^i$. Since these polynomials are the same, $a_i = 0$ for all $i$ odd.

That, of course, does not put a restriction on the other $a_i$ i.e. when $i$ is even.

To show that $W$ is a subspace, simply note that if $p,q \in W$, then $(p+q)(-x) = p(-x)+q(-x) = p(x)+q(x) = (p+q)(x)$. Similarly, $(kp)(-x) = k(p(-x)) = k(p(x)) = (kp)(x)$ for all scalars $k$.

Hence, $W$ is a subspace. It's easy to see that a basis for $W$ is formed by the even powers of $x$ less than or equal to $n$, since $p = \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$, but then all the odd $i$ coefficients are zero, so only the even $i$ coefficients are left behind. Also, of course this set of even powers of $x$ is linearly independent (since if a linear combination of them is equal to zero, then all the coefficients must be zero by the fundamental theorem of algebra).

Hence, the dimension of $W$ is the number of even numbers less than or equal to $n$ (including $0$). For $n$ odd, it is $\frac{n+1}2$, and for $n$ even, it is $\frac n2 + 1$.